# Appending br to a span

Tags: javascript, dom

I have an HTML page with a span as shown below:

```
<span id="lbUsers"></span>
```

And I populate the span using this JavaScript method:

```
document.getElementById("lbUsers").appendChild(document.createTextNode
              (row.UserId + ". " + row.FirstName+ " " + row.LastName));
```

This works just fine and the elements are displayed. However, since there are no line breaks, they appear as such:

```
1. FN1 LN1 2. FN2 LN2 3. FN3 LN3 (.....)
```

And I want to to instead appear as such:

```
1. FN1 LN1
2. FN2 LN2
3. FN3 LN3
(...)
```

So far, I have tried to declare my own break line by doing:

```
var lineBreak = document.createElement("br");
```

And I use this line after the first append:

```
document.getElementById("lbUsers").appendChild(document.createTextNode
             (row.UserId + ". " + row.FirstName+ " " + row.LastName));

document.getElementById("lbUsers").appendChild(lineBreak);
```

However, it does not seem to work as the results are still shown next to each other and not listed.

Any ideas?

Comment: A variation of your code works fine for me: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLQh5/). Remember to add the br element after you append each element.

Comment: Rather than look up your `lbUsers` element all the time, you should just save a reference, eg `var lbUsers = document.getElementById('lbUsers')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not enough to create BR element once, you have to create a new one every time you need a line break, might as well create it inline:

```
document.getElementById("lbUsers").appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZEkCP/

Comment: Thanks, this works. Though what's the logic behind the need to create a new line break every time you need one?

Comment: Because technically you are having many line breaks and not just one. As another answer (now removed) pointed out if you create it only once  - every consecutive `.appendChild` just moves it to a new position, removing from old one.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the br after LastName like this:

```
document.getElementById("lbUsers").appendChild(document.createTextNode
          (row.UserId + ". " + row.FirstName+ " " + row.LastName + "<br>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple additive assignment make wonders:

```
document.getElementById("lbUsers").innerHTML += row.UserId +'. '+ row.FirstName +' '+ row.LastName + '<br>'
```